# When was Java's 'qualified this' introduced?

Tags: java, history

I've only recently learned about the *[qualified this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4)*, and was curious as to when was it introduced in the language, as I've been using Java here and there for around 18 years.

Oracle keeps only the specifications for Java SE up to 6, but I cannot find any earlier versions online. I'm curious if it was there all this time (but I never paid attention to it) or is it something introduced later.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the answer after some additional searching: It was introduced in Java 1.2.
It's not in the [1.0](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/) specification, but it appears in [2.0](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-2.0/expressions.doc.html#251603).

Comment: So there is life without this :)

Comment: @SilviuBurcea There's certainly a life without `Java.this` (:-p

Answer (score 1):

Qualified this was introduced along with inner classes in Java 1.1. However, 1.1 was introduced without a whole new Java Language Specification (JLS). The changes are in separate documents that specify the differences from Java 1.0.

[You may need the Wayback Machine.](http://web.archive.org/web/20000110005200/http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/1.1/docs/guide/innerclasses/spec/innerclasses.doc8.html) Although there is an [Inner Classes Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/JLS/innerclasses.pdf) on the JCP site.